# A* pathfinding heuristic not working properly

Tags: lua, path-finding, a-star

I don't know what the issue is exactly but I believe the heuristic function is doing something funky.

Breadth search works 100% normally.

[image: 1]

But when I add in the heuristic function for priority it just suddenly does really weird stuff, resulting in completely strange paths.

[image: 2]

Not just that but it doesn't even finish making the pathing grids (came-from, cost-so-far-and-such), stopping just before the ending.

Then when I try to add the A* part and it's still weird.

[image: 3]

At first I didn't mind but after fiddling it just doesn't make sense, I've tried moving things around and trying to figure out if it's something to do with when it's inserted to the table or if it's the Manhattan distance heuristic itself but I've done everything as correctly as I can think to.

Here's my update code:

```lua
function updategraph(graph, frontier, camefrom, costsofar, goal)
    -- continue while there are entries in the frontier
    if #frontier > 0 then
        local pos = frontier[1]
        
        -- go over all neighbours
        for i, p in ipairs(getcons(graph, pos)) do
            local oldcost = costsofar[pos[1]] and costsofar[pos[1]][pos[2]] or 0
            local newcost = (graph[p[1]][p[2]].cost or 1) + oldcost
            
            local hascsf = (costsofar[p[1]] and costsofar[p[1]][p[2]])
            local solid = (graph[p[1]] and graph[p[1]][p[2]] and graph[p[1]][p[2]].solid)
            
            if not solid and
                (not hascsf
                or (hascsf and newcost < costsofar[pos[1]][pos[2]]))
            then
                if not camefrom[p[1]] then camefrom[p[1]] = {} end
                camefrom[p[1]][p[2]] = pos
                
                if not costsofar[p[1]] then costsofar[p[1]] = {} end
                costsofar[p[1]][p[2]] = newcost
                
                -- use heuristic to find the priority
                local priority = math.max(1, math.min(#frontier, newcost + heuristic(goal, p)))
                table.insert(frontier, priority, p)
                
                -- if the current position is the goal
                if goal[1] == p[1] and goal[2] == p[2] then
                    return false
                end
            end
        end
        
        -- remove from the frontier
        table.remove(frontier, 1)
    end
end
```

The heuristic:

```lua
function heuristic(goal, nxt)
    -- manhattan distance on a square grid
    return math.abs(goal[1] - nxt[1]) + math.abs(goal[2] - nxt[2])
end
```

Code for getting neighbours/connections:

```lua
function getcons(graph, pos)
    -- acquire neighbours
    local r = {}
    
    -- make sure the grid space exists before adding it to the neighbours list
    if graph[pos[1]+1] and graph[pos[1]+1][pos[2]] then
        table.insert(r, {pos[1]+1, pos[2]})
    end
    if graph[pos[1]-1] and graph[pos[1]-1][pos[2]] then
        table.insert(r, {pos[1]-1, pos[2]})
    end
    if graph[pos[1]] and graph[pos[1]][pos[2]+1] then
        table.insert(r, {pos[1], pos[2]+1})
    end
    if graph[pos[1]] and graph[pos[1]][pos[2]-1] then
        table.insert(r, {pos[1], pos[2]-1})
    end
    
    return r
end
```

Apologies if I've asked anything incorrectly, tell me and I'll give any more needed information.

Comment: You have implemented priority queue incorrectly.  It can not be implemented in only 2 lines of code :-)

Comment: How so? What did I miss?

Comment: `table.insert(frontier, priority, p)` inserts value `p` into `frontier[priority]`  But why do you think it is the right place?